# Facebook graph api- how to get user feed,with out posts about likes and comment by the user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

i am developing a fb app,in which i want to give the users time line,but i need to exclude stories like "User likes a photo","coments on friends's photo".how i filter and exclude these types of stories

Answer (score 2):

You can filter these [Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) by looking for the presence of the `story` or `story_tags` key as these is not present in the Posts made by the User.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) the description of `story` key

> Text of stories not intentionally generated by users, such as those generated when two users become friends; you must have the "Include recent activity stories" migration enabled in your app to retrieve these stories

Or you may try FQL's [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) like this

```
select message from stream where source_id=me() and type in (46,56,80,56,128,247)
and filter_key in (select filter_key from stream_filter where uid=me())
```

which might help you to reduce the Posts to one that you desire.

**Update**

You might not require to reduce the result using `type` field as verified by 林果皞 , so the query reduces to

```
select message from stream where source_id=me() AND filter_key in
(select filter_key from stream_filter where uid=me())
```

Comment: Your answer is correct compare with me. But i found it's not require to do type in (46,56,80,56,128,247) at all. "select message from stream where source_id=me() AND filter_key in (select filter_key from stream_filter where uid=me())" is enough already, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah it maybe, I just added those to be sure.. :-) :-P

Comment: Bad news, the query may return duplicate post, please see my screenshot at stackoverflow.com/questions/16481191/…. Also, i found post to page's type is 164, however i'm not sure the wall's type is always only (46,56,80,56,128,247) type

Comment: story may also be included when the user "shares". And this may be part of the feed for the use case

Answer (score 1):

Use fql, the "type" field is "null" if the description is something like "A followed B", "A likes Intel.", "A commented on his own link."...etc:

```
SELECT created_time,description,likes,message,post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND type!="" AND created_time<=now() LIMIT 50
```

**Update:**
I found my query doesn't exclude post on page story, Anvesh Saxena's answer is correct than mine.

> select message from stream where source_id=me() AND filter_key in (select filter_key from stream_filter where uid=me())

**Update Wed may 15 2013:**
    Seem we have trouble because different filter_key may have hold the same post_id. For example, some link may appear both at "nf" filter_key and Links filter_key "app_2309869772"
    [image]

**Update:i do some research and finally come out this query(Replace 2 "me()" to other user_id is works too):**

> SELECT viewer_id, app_id, target_id, post_id, created_time, message,
>   type, permalink FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND
>   created_time<=now() AND ((type IN(46,80,128,237,247)) OR (type="" AND
>   target_id=me())) LIMIT 150

This FQL API query compare with web browser(I tested with clicked "All stories" on my wall):

Advantage:

- All duplicated feeds which was created within short period of time would included. Web browser version may exclude this duplicated feeds.

Disadvantage:

- "tagged by somebody" wouldn't included(It's make sense because the source id is not me(), and no point to query all friends and filter by me() IN(tagged_ids) because of performance concern)
- "Update cover photo" and "Update profile photo" feed wouldn't included.
- I found there's case user's post via mobile doesn't return from stream table even specific the post_id, it's nothing we can do.
- "(type="" AND target_id=me())" doesn't works when your friend share photo and links on your timeline. Status shared by friend is works.

Kindly inform me if somebody have better query

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

All the json data you get from Graph api when requesting users feed, has an element 'type' which can be e.g. Link, comment, status.... Chose the ones you need.

Comment: but for this ["story"]=>string(28) "abcd likes a link.",the type i am getting as status,then how i recognize it is about a like,for comments i am getting type as user

Comment: Check if it has a image url in it. If yes than it is a picture otherwise it is a link. There might be other deferences. You must look through all of them and filter.

Comment: Ok I found the solution. Just add 'me/feed?fields=picture'

Comment: But then you can't use limit effectiverly.