# feed, home, post not giving actual wall posts in Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve Facebook wall posts of a user using Facebook C# SDK.

I am using feed connection, but what it gives me the entries which are shown in "Activity Log" section in my Facebook account not those which are shown on my Wall. Do I need some special parameters or anything? Can someone please point me into right direction?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481191/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-feed-with-out-posts-about-likes-and-comment/16481826#16481826

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my problem is not in filtering data, I am not actually getting all of it. Hope that clarifies the problem.

Comment: Which post you're not actually getting by using graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed? Can you give one public post_id as example?

Comment: When I go to my Facebook account there are entries on my wall which are show to me as shown as I log in(this is what I want to fetch), What I am getting is the contents of Activity log section under my profile. I am quite new to Facebook API, so I am not sure what you are referring as public "post_id". If you can please point me in right direction I can provide required input. Thanks.

Comment: Currently if you request "graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed" API, you would get the contents of Activity log section(including wall feed). That's why we have a discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481191/ to filter out story(activity) and remains the feed which we can see on wall.

Comment: post_id(or simply id) is a unique identity of a post, which you can get from request to "graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed" OR FQL API

Comment: i have update my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481191/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-feed-with-out-posts-about-likes-and-comment/16481761#16481761, can you try this FQL query instead?

Comment: Facebook have changed the API response, /feed connection would include "100000566619686_629431233752425" "likes a page" story feed and other activities, such as "followed someone", "using profile in English", "comment on someone post"...etc story feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finally figured it out. It was an issue with permissions not being passed correctly(due to a silly coding mistake). I was only getting "AccessToken" without any permissions. I added required permissions and it worked as expected.
Anyways, Thanks for the help.