# Remove posts for user likes and user comments Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybridauth

I currently experimenting with HybridAuth and Facebook Graph API. 
I get news feed from Facebook API with `$fb->api()->api("/me/home?limit=10");`.

But I get post with text "*User* likes" a photo or "*User* comments on status". How can I remove those posts from array with posts?

Just for notice, I get array with parameters for each post. Those posts which I want to exclude have "story_tags", and other does not have it.

Can you help me? Maybe my API call is wrong, or I should add something more in API call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481191/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-feed-with-out-posts-about-likes-and-comment similar question here

Comment: Yes, but they using FQL, and I'm using url query and I dont know how to use FQL in url query